# VIsual Studio Perforce - build errors trying to figure out where to specify p4 password

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, perforce

I just installed visual studio perforce plug in and I selected it as my source control in the option settings.

I added a P4Config.txt file with my PORT, user, client, editor

I then using the VS Open Connection to Peforce depot I enter my settings which I know are correct because I got them from when I connect using the standalone P4 tool.
It spins for a while and does NOT ask for password.
There is now an option to disconnect so i assumed i was conected.

If I do a build it gives me the following error

Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset.

How do I set the password or have it prompt when I try to connect. I didn'' see any options

Comment: Are you utilizing Active Directory or just P4 passwords?  Also what is the security level set in the P4 Admin console?